# Erro ao executar projeto no Visual Studio 2015 - Process with an id 7256 is not running

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio, iis

Estou tentando executar um projeto que desenvolvi e esta acontecendo este erro.

**Process with an id 7256 is not running.**

O que devo fazer para solucionar este problema.

Comment: Olha, tem essa resposta no SO-en talvez possa ajudar http://stackoverflow.com/a/27155236/5784670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleta o arquivo **applicationhost** na pasta .vs/config. Comigo funcionou...

Answer (score 0):

Amigo. tenta isto:

1. Fecha todas as instâncias do Visual Studio
2. Renomeia a pasta IISExpress no seu diretorio do usuario(ex:
   C:\Users\OlavoNeto\Documents)
3. Adiciona a variável de ambiente
       _CSRUN_DISABLE_WORKAROUNDS; veja [aqui](http://gauravmantri.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image_thumb.png) como
4. Inicie o visual studio como administrador

Comment: Esta acontecendo agora este problema, quando executo no Chrome.
Não é possível acessar esse site

A conexão com localhost foi recusada.
Pesquise localhost 56243 no Google
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Amigo, tenta isto no seu Internet explorer, pode ser uma configuração de proxy   clica em Propriedades de Internet > Conexões > Configurações de LAN e desmarquei a opção USAR UM SERVIDOR PROXY PARA A REDE LOCAL

Comment: Já fui nesta opção USAR UM SERVIDOR PROXY PARA A REDE LOCAL e ela esta desmarcada, amigo não dá para entender.

Comment: Amigos, eu formatei minha máquina, eu lembro que aconteceu algo assim outra vez, ai tive que desabilitar no projeto através do Visual Studio uma verificação que é feita, ai quando desativei a opção de verificação funcionou. O problema que não lembro onde desativo esta verificação de Id

Comment: acredito que esta seja a solução http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190881/how-to-solve-err-connection-refused-when-trying-to-connect-to-localhost-running

Comment: Infelizmente não é isto, lembro que tinha de desabilitar uma verificação de autenticidade de projeto, algo assim, lembro que desabilitei e funcionou, quando falo que lembro é que teve outra vez que formatei minha máquina e após formatar aconteceu este mesmo problema.

Comment: Encontrei o erro, esta descrito aqui:

Faça assim vá na pasta do projeto e na pasta .vs/config deletar o arquivo applicationhost